# Google Cloud Compute load balancing and auto scaling info NOT written for sysadmin type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, autoscaling

I asked this on serverfault but evidently to basic for them.

I have read through a ton of documents on the Google cloud platform but most of it is over my head, I am a developer and not a network type person. I think what I am trying to do is pretty basic but I can't find anywhere that has step by step instructions on how to accomplish the process. Google documentation seems to assume a good deal of networking knowledge.

I have :

- created a "managed instance group" with Autoscaling turned on.
- RDP'd into the server and installed the required software
- upload all the code to run a site
- set up DNS to point to that site
- tested and everything seems to work just as I would expect.

I need to set up a load balancer and change the DNS to point to that instead of the server.

My web app doesn't have a back-end perse as it is entirely api driven so not sure what to do with the "backend configuration" part of setting up the load balance service.

I have an SSL cert on the server but don't know how to move it to the load balancer.

When the autoscaling kicks in will all the software and code from the current server be used or is there another step that I need to do to make this happen. If I update code on the server via RDP will the new autoscale created instances be aware of it?

Can anyone explain these steps to point me to a place NOT written for a sysadmin that I can try to understand them myself?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sharing with you a [short YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9CTezyJ7yo) (less than 5 mins) of step by step instructions on how to quickly configure a load balancer in Google Cloud Platform with backend services.

I also would like to mention here that SSL terminates at the load balancer. Here is the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) on Creating and Using SSL Certificates in load balancing.

Finally, you want to make sure that all the software and configurations you want on each instance is done before you create the managed instance group, otherwise, the changes you make on one server will not reflect in the others.

To do this, configure your server with all the necessary software and settings. Once the server is in the correct state, [create an image out of your server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#deleteinstance). You can then use this image to [create an instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) which you will use for the managed instance group.